# unable to get data from ajax calls to show notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

using 2 ajax calls to show notification in layout. first ajax call data is coming and showing notificaition but seconc function not getting data and not showing any notification

code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            LoadNotification();
            LoadTankNotification();
            setInterval(function () {
                LoadNotification();
                LoadTankNotification();
            }, 30000);

            function LoadNotification() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetBinNotification", "smartbin")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            $(".binnotification .binlabel").text(data.model.length);
                            $(".binnotification .dropdown-menu > li.header").text('you have ' + data.model.length + ' bins are filled');
                            var htmlofNotification = '';
                            $(data.model).each(function (i, item) {
                                item.Filled = item.Filled.toFixed(2);
                                htmlofNotification += '<li>' +
                                    '<a href="#">' +
                                        '<h3>' + item.BinName + '<small class="pull-right">' + item.Filled + '%</small>' + '</h3>' +
                                        '<div class="progress xs">' +
                                            '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: ' + item.Filled + '%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + item.Filled + '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">' +
                                                '<span class="sr-only">' + item.Filled + '% Complete</span>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</a>' +
                                '</li>';
                            });
                            $('.binnotification .dropdown-menu ul.menu').html(htmlofNotification);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            //notification for water tank kadma
            function LoadTankNotification() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetWaterNotification", "WaterLevel")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            $(".tanknotification .tanklabel").text(data.model.length);
                            $(".tanknotification .dropdown-menu > li.header").text('you have ' + data.model.length + ' bins are filled');
                            var htmlofNotification1 = '';
                            $(data.model).each(function (i, item) {
                                item.Filled = item.Filled.toFixed(2);
                                htmlofNotification1 += '<li>' +
                                    '<a href="#">' +
                                        '<h3>' + item.watertankName + '<small class="pull-right">' + item.Filled + '%</small>' + '</h3>' +
                                        '<div class="progress xs">' +
                                            '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: ' + item.Filled + '%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + item.Filled + '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">' +
                                                '<span class="sr-only">' + item.Filled + '% Complete</span>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</a>' +
                                '</li>';
                            });
                            $('.tanknotification .dropdown-menu ul.menu').html(htmlofNotification1);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });


    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8yaw2y9/

Comment: any errors in browser's console ? what is the status of the second ajax request ? and what result does the server returns(whether error or data) ?

Comment: second method giving error - xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );//Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i got the error and resolved. server was there

Comment: next time my friend, if you want to comment on my comment mention me(@niceman) :)

Comment: by the way, answer your question so that we know that your problem is solved